# Site hacked but file dates remain unchanged?

Tags: php, html, security

So my index.php file was hacked and simply overwritten with a string of text. When I went to look at the files I noticed the date modified remained unchanged. I did not think this was possible?? Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't care about dates. You should care about your site being hacked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's native [`touch()`](http://php.net/touch) function's second argument is the timestamp to set the file to. It's trivially faked.

Comment: See this post: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32929/how-to-edit-files-without-changing-the-last-modified-date